# PHP stripping from HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use PHP to return three simple variables from a web page. The web page is: http://areacode.org/519 My code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<?php
//variables
    $quickurl = idk;
    $country = idk;
    $State = idk;
    $city = idk;
//end of variables
    $test = file_get_contents("http://areacode.org/519");
    //$strip = strip_tags($test); Not sure if this is needed.
    echo ("<center>Info about Area code! Country: ".$country.". State: ".$state.". City: ".$city.". Quick reference URL: ".$quickurl."</center>");
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to strip out the country, state, and major city and the quick url. I have looked around, but no help. I think I may just be a little confused. Any help?

Comment: If I understand you, you're trying to get the Country, State, and city from the URL `http://areacode.org/519`?  What you are trying to do is called "Screen Scraping" (or "Web Scraping").  You need to use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/DOM) for this.

Comment: PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is probably what I'd use. Given that your requirement is relatively simple, a couple of Regexes might do what you need, but be careful: HTML and Regex don't mix well.

Comment: @MikeW: While, regex *could* be a solution, I wouldn't realistically suggest it.  Especially not to a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is DOM and XPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://areacode.org/519');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$data = $xpath->query("//div[@class='info']//span[@class='value']");
list($country, $state, $city, $url) = array_map(function ($node) {
        return trim($node->nodeValue, "\xc2\xa0"); // strip non-breaking spaces found on source
    }, iterator_to_array($data));
var_dump($country, $state, $city, $url);
```

This gave me the following:

```
string(6) "Canada"
string(7) "Ontario"
string(6) "London"
string(16) "areacode.org/519"
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Use $pos = strpos($test, "label"); for get the position of the data you are looking for, and then substr(); to catch it, easy to start.
Or u can use the correct way:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php